# Problemas ao criar um evento

Tags: mysql

Estou tentando criar um evento mas obtenho o erro abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E minha query:

```
CREATE EVENT insert_count
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 50 SECOND
COMMENT 'bla bla bla bla bla bla.'
DO BEGIN
INSERT INTO teste (nome, conectado, desconectado)
SELECT parceiro.nomeP AS 'Parceiro', 
SUM(di.connectedOr = 'true') AS 'ClientesConectados', 
SUM(di.connectedOr = 'false') AS 'ClientesDesconectados'
FROM vpn AS di
JOIN parceiro
ON parceiro.codParceiro = di.idpartner
WHERE di.comName REGEXP 'skytef-'
GROUP BY di.idpartner
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Conforme documentação sobre [Create Event](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html), alterei seu scripts adicionando o comando `Delimiter`, pois assim temporiamente o MySql ignora o `;`, para executar o comando em um bloco, algo assim.
Mais detalhes consulte [Defining Stored Programs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html).

Espero que te ajude.

```
delimiter |
CREATE EVENT insert_count
    ON SCHEDULE
       EVERY 50 SECOND
    COMMENT 'bla bla bla bla bla bla.'
    DO 
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO teste (nome, conectado, desconectado)
        SELECT parceiro.nomep AS 'Parceiro'
              ,SUM(di.connectedor = 'true') AS 'ClientesConectados'
              ,SUM(di.connectedor = 'false') AS 'ClientesDesconectados'
          FROM vpn AS di
          JOIN parceiro
            ON parceiro.codparceiro = di.idpartner
         WHERE di.comname regexp 'skytef-'
         GROUP BY di.idpartner;
    END |

delimiter;
```

Comment: Erro SQL (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'delimiter' at line 1